# $k$-invariants of $KO$ and $ko$ and differentials in the AHSS spectral sequence

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $KO$ and $ko$ denote real $K$-theory and connective real $K$-theory.  It appears to be a well done  result that the $k$-invariants can be used to determine the early differentials in the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for a generalised cohomology theory.

In the case of $KO$ and $ko$ one finds that the differentials are

- $Sq^2\circ r: H\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\Sigma^2H\mathbb{Z}_2$,
- $Sq^2: H\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow\Sigma^2H\mathbb{Z}_2$,
- $\beta_2\circ Sq^2:H\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow\Sigma^3H\mathbb{Z}$.

Here $r$ is reduction modulo $2$ and $\beta_2$ is the Bockstein.

My question is what is a reference for this? (A reference for the differentials for both $KO$ and $ko$ will suffice.)

Comment: Section 5.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.07059 gives these formulas, as well as references.

Comment: @BertramArnold Do you know of any reference for the case of $\widetilde{ko}_*$?